# How to get a MenuItem from within its CanExecute handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem, canexecute

How can I get access to the related `MenuItem`? It has been created on the fly, so I cannot just use it by a name in the xaml file.

```
private void menuItem_canExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var snd = sender; // This is the main window
    var orgSource = e.OriginalSource; // This is a RichTextBox;
    var src = e.Source; // This is a UserControl

    // I think I must use the Command, but how?
    RoutedCommand routedCommand = e.Command as RoutedCommand;
}
```

Comment: You could bind the MenuItem's `CommandParameter` to the MenuItem instance, like `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` and than access it by the `Parameter` property of the CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.

Comment: Why do you need access to the `MenuItem`? Maybe there is a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Clemens: This is a working solution, please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @StillLearnin: In the subitems of a menu "Document" I insert a new item if the user opens a document. After he has closed the document he can easily reopen it by the new menu item. The menu item text consists of a leading number and the document name. To solve the access problem I can use Clemens' proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass the commanding UI element to a command by binding itself to its `CommandParameter` property, like

```
<MenuItem ... CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Now you can access the MenuItem by the `Parameter` property of the CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs:

```
private void menuItem_canExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = e.Parameter as MenuItem;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs` has an `OriginalSource` property.

[MSDN Doc for CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.canexecuteroutedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

The `OriginalSender` will probably be a `TextBlock` which is "inside" the `MenuItem`. You will likely need to traverse the visual tree to find the `parent` which is of type `MenuItem`

Sample code from [here](http://www.journeyintocode.com/2013/03/wpf-find-parent-by-type.html)

```
public static T GetVisualParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : Visual
{
    //TODO wrap this in a loop to keep climbing the tree till the correct type is found 
    //or till we reach the end and haven't found the type
    Visual parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) as Visual;
    if (parentObject == null) return null;
    return parentObject is T ? parentObject as T : GetVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
}
```

Used like this

```
var menuItem = e.OriginalSource.GetVisualParent<MenuItem>();
if (menuItem != null)
    //Do something....
```

Comment: If I search the tree for a `MenuItem` I must have at least one unique property which is not there.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear on what I am suggesting you try.

Comment: I tried your proposal, but `e.OriginalSource` in my case is a `RichTextBox` and `GetVisualParent<MenuItem>(...)` always returns null.